# Can I set DNS Server for local machine using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, networking, dns, electron

Is there any way in Node.js that I can set local machine's DNS server. For example, I'm planning to build an Electron app which can change my Internet's DNS server to 9.9.9.9 whenever I click on a button.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this will be highly dependent on the OS if it’s possible at all.